# Как сделать абсолютное позиционирование блока относительно окна браузера внутри блока с фиксированным позиционированием?

Tags: css

Есть сайт, у которого верхнее меню зафиксировано.
Внутри него есть блок `.profile_btn` *(Блок **"Андрей"**)*.
Внутри блока `.profile_btn`есть блок с меню с абсолютным позиционированием.
Как можно сделать верхнее меню фиксированным, а подменю с абсолютным позиционированием относительно окна, чтобы прокручивалось вместе со страницей?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не понимаю, в чем проблема у вас http://codepen.io/bustexz/pen/pbzNqQ?editors=1100

Comment: Красный блок у вас по моему описанию должен крутиться вместе со страницей.

Comment: ну у меня он и крутится вместе со страницей, проверил в хроме и лисе

Comment: Он во всех браузерах фиксированный. Стоит на месте при прокрутке.

Comment: красный блок с абсолютной позицией, двигается вместе с фиксированной шапкой, все как вы и написали

Comment: Я спросил, как подменю сделать абсолютным относительно ОКНА, а не синего блока. Чтобы при прокрутке синее меню всегда было вверху, а подменю при прокрутке уходило вверх, как и вся страница. В вашем же случае то, что у меня есть сейчас. Фиксированы как меню, так и подменю.

Comment: Средствами css не сделать. Как вариант попробуйте вынести это всплывающее меню из дочерних блока Андрей и вообще из фиксированного меню в боди. А затем при открывании просто корректируйте его левую и верхнюю позицию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
      $(".head").addClass("relat");
    } else {
      $(".head").removeClass("relat");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}

.head {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: blue;
  position: fixed;
}

.fixedBlock {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  right: 20px;
}
.relat{
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="head">
  <div class="fixedBlock"></div>
</div>
```

Надо воспользоваться jquery : `if  else`

Comment: .head должен быть фиксированным.

Comment: он там фиксированный